# Do I need "shell" runner if I want to deploy gitlab + ansible on the same box?

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, cd

I've have seen a gitlab demo about using [Infrastructure as code](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/07/01/using-ansible-and-gitlab-as-infrastructure-for-code/). If I wanted to do the same on-prem, would this work? Setup open-source gitlab on-prem, setup a bash as shell runner, and using the shell runner, execute ansible playbooks on the network equipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*having written out this answer, I now believe this question is at risk of closure for being either Too Broad or Primarily Opinion Based; but, I already spent the effort to type it out, so here we go.*

> Setup open-source gitlab on-prem, setup a bash as shell runner, and using the shell runner, execute ansible playbooks on the network equipment?

I believe that's possible, or you can install ansible, along with any required python modules for your playbooks, into a docker image and then use the docker executor to run the playbooks inside a container. Using [Tower or AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme) is also possible, since they have the concept of [projects run from source control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.5.2/html/userguide/projects.html#manage-playbooks-using-source-control)

The advantage of using the docker runner is that you don't have to pre-install ansible (along with its dependencies) on every runner host; the disadvantage of using the docker runner is that I could imagine ssh authentication from inside the container getting weird.

```
# hypothetical .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
- apply
run ansible playbook:
  stage: apply
  image: docker.example.com/my-ansible:2.8
  scripts:
  - ansible-playbook -i ./some-inventory -v playbook.yml
```

The advantage of using a dedicated system like AWX (or Tower) is that the inventory against which those playbooks run is also a formally managed entity in the system, and wouldn't require teaching GitLab about how to make that available to your playbook. Same story with the authentication, since AWX has first-class support for a managed SSH keypair that can be conditionally granted to only certain playbook projects

You can still have GitLab integrate with Tower by either using [tower-cli](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli#readme) or [their rich API](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_launch_create) to launch a Job Template that has its Project configured to do an SCM update before launch

Comment: Thank you for your insight!